# List has no rows for assignment to SObject - Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, help

Another one of these, I know.  I have been looking at similar errors for the last few hours with no luck.  I tried using a "Try" "Catch" workaround with no luck, I tried using an Array, I tried making everything visible to the test class.  I had no luck with anything, so hopefully someone here can help me out!

From what I understand, I'm getting the error because my list is returning no values, and that isn't allowed.  How would I get around this in my particular case?

Here is my CLASS

```
public class UserContact {
    @future public static void createUserContact(set<ID> recordIDs){
        list<user> users = [SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, email, name, CommunityNickname, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey 
                            FROM user
                            WHERE ID in :recordIDs];
        for (user x: users){
            Account Accountx = [SELECT ID
                                FROM account];
            Contact userCon = new contact(
            AccountID = AccountX.id,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            email = x.Email);
            insert userCon;
            usercon.account.Name = 'Company Internal';
        }
    }
}`
```

Here is my TRIGGER

```
trigger NewUserCreatedTrigger on User (after insert) {
    user[] users = trigger.new;
UserContact.createUserContact(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
```

Here is my TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
private class UserContactTest {
testmethod static void userCreationTest(){
    //User u = UserContact.createUserContact(User.id); //Commented as it is not required
    User u = new User();
    u.Firstname = 'mike';
    u.LastName = 'Smith';
    u.email = 'msmith@company.com';
    u.Alias = 'alias';
    u.CommunityNickname = 'commnick';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.Username = 'msmith@company.com';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Denver';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.ProfileId = [SELECT id FROM profile where Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;
    insert u;
}
```

I'm still learning, going through the trailhead modules and other online tutorials, but going through these errors is helping me learn a lot, so I'm trying to work through them at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to wrap your future method in Test.startTest() and Test.EndTest() so test execution will wait for the future method to execute. List is probably returning no rows because the future method hasn't executed yet.

Comment: As illustrated in @Sebastian Kessel's answer, make sure you constrain the results of the SOQL query. Assigning the results of a SOQL query to a single SObject rather than a List results in a runtime failure unless there is 1 and only 1 result.

You could change it to:
`List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];`

Or add a where clause or LIMIT clause...

Comment: Thank you!  I started learning Apex maybe a week ago and have been working on this ever since.  It is a project handed to me by my supervisor, and by going through all the problems like this, I'm learning faster than if I was only doing the trailhead.

So, I would be setting this limit to avoid the 100-200 limit on queries right?

Comment: You are querying the Account table. If you get more than 1 row and attempt to assign that to your Accountx variable you will get the opposite of your original problem - `System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject`!

So one way of guarding against this would be to use `Account accountx = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your problem is this line

`Account Accountx = [SELECT ID FROM account];`

and then

`AccountID = AccountX.id,`

Since test code cannot see any data, there are no accounts to assign. Make sure you create an account in your test code, like the sample below.

```
@isTest
private class UserContactTest {
testmethod static void userCreationTest(){
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Company Internal');
    insert a;

    User u = new User();
    u.Firstname = 'mike';
    u.LastName = 'Smith';
    u.email = 'msmith@company.com';
    u.Alias = 'alias';
    u.CommunityNickname = 'commnick';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.Username = 'msmith@company.com';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Denver';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.ProfileId = [SELECT id FROM profile where Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;

   insert u;
}
```

***However***, that will fix your test failure but won't make your code work. In your trigger, you are making a SoQL query within a loop. That is a big no-no.

I am going to go ahead and assume that you do not want to get a "usercon" record created for each account in the system. That means a better way to query, and a way of figuring out which account you want to use.

With that, here is a possible example, assuming all users will go to the same account

```
public class UserContact {
    @future public static void createUserContact(set<ID> recordIDs){
        list<user> users = [SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, email, name, CommunityNickname, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey 
                            FROM user
                            WHERE ID in :recordIDs];

        String accountName = 'Company Internal'; //This is where you will provide your name (could be any other field)

        //In this query you want to "LIMIT 1" to avoid more than 1 record returning
        Account Accountx = [SELECT ID
                                FROM account
                               where Name = :accountName
                               LIMIT 1];

        List<contact> contactsToCreate = new List<Contact>();
        for (user x: users){
            Contact userCon = new contact(
            AccountID = AccountX.id,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            email = x.Email);
            contactsToCreate.add(userCon);
        }
        insert contactsToCreate;
    }
}
```

My example is almost trivial. Let me know your use case (i.e.: how do you determine the account to choose) and I can improve my sample code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I will in a few minutes.

The idea is that every time someone creates a user, a contact is automatically created and populated with some of the same information

Comment: You're welcome, Let me know!

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting the enter key before I want to post, edited the original post to explain my use case.

I wouldn't touch accounts, except that when I tried to just tie Contacts to Users, it wouldn't let me, I believe because of the master-detail relationship between Accounts and Users.  The only thing I'm trying to accomplish is to create a contact whenever a user is created, and give the contact the same information.

I used Process Builder to do this, but it couldn't do the final part, setting the contact account name to "company internal".  Which is vital.

Comment: I just updated my code (both the class and the test code). That should do it for you. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Just changed mine to match yours, and I got
"expecting right curly bracket, found 'EOF'"
On line 23

Maybe because I copied and pasted?

Comment: I can't find the offending extra bracket, but it is possible you have an extra (or missed) a curly bracket. Is this in your test class or regular one?

Comment: Frup, is this a comment on my code or on the OP's? My sample includes a `LIMIT 1` clause.

Comment: OP.
I thought it made sense here where the discussion was continuing, but happy to delete the comment and add instead against the OP.

Comment: The OP's is where it belongs. :)

Comment: All the help is more than welcome!

I found the offending bracket in the test class.  After running the test, I am met with two errors,

The first is 

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, pse_resource.populateLatitudeAndLongitudeByMailingAddress: execution of AfterInsert


The second is

 caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: pse_resource.GeoLocationManager.handleResourceChanges(Set<Id>)

Comment: What is weird however, is that both the trigger and the class passed 100%

Comment: Let's continue this on [chat]... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37638/list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject-test-class