# List has no rows for assignment to SObject error in apex test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

This issue is connected with this post: [MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation error when creating user role record in test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211716/mixed-dml-operation-dml-operation-error-when-creating-user-role-record-in-test/211718?noredirect=1#comment320403_211718) but I've decided to post this as another topic since this is a much different issue.

This includes `UserRole` object wherein selected role name must be assigned to a field in `Setting__c` custom setting.

I hope that this would not be tagged as duplicate as this is different from other posts I've seen, and as I am just seeking for some help.

Please bear with me, and thanks in advance.

I encounter this error after I run the test class:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Error pertains to this line of codes:

`UserRole ur = [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id =: selectedRole];` from the controller and

to this line of code: `uadc2.save();` from the test class itself.

How can I resolve this?

**Apex Class:**

```
public class SettingClass {

    private ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public Setting__c settingRec {get;set;}
    public List<SettingWrapper> swraplist {get;set;} 
    public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}
    public String selectedRole {get;set;}
    public String selectedStat {get;set;}

    public SettingClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con = controller;
        this.settingRec = (Setting__c)controller.getRecord();
        swraplist = new List<SettingWrapper>();
        addNewRow();

    }
    public void addNewRow() {
        List<SettingWrapper> temp_wrap = new List<SettingWrapper>();
        SettingWrapper newSetting = new SettingWrapper();

        Item__c newItemRecord = new Item__c();      
        newSetting.set1 = newItemRecord;
        newSetting.index = temp_wrap.size();
        temp_wrap.add(newSetting);
        for(SettingWrapper sw : temp_wrap) {
            swraplist.add(sw);
        }
    }

    public void removeRow() {
        List<SettingWrapper> rem_wrap = new List<SettingWrapper>();
        for(SettingWrapper sw : swraplist) {
            rem_wrap.add(sw);
        }
        rem_wrap.remove(rowToRemove);
        swraplist.clear();
        for(SettingWrapper sw2 : rem_wrap) {
            swraplist.add(sw2);
        }
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getUserRoleList() {
        List<UserRole> urList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole];
        List<SelectOption> urOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        urOptionList.add(new SelectOption(' ',' '));

        for(UserRole ur : urList) {
            urOptionList.add(new SelectOption(ur.Id, ur.Name));    
        }

        return urOptionList;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getStatList() {
        List<SelectOption> statOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult statResults = Account.Status__c.getDescribe();

        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = statResults.getPicklistValues();

        for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            statOptionList.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));    
        }  

        return statOptionList;
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        List<SettingWrapper> swList = new List<SettingWrapper>();
        List<Item__c> newItemList = new List<Item__c>();


        for(SettingWrapper sw : swraplist) {
            swList.add(sw);
        }

        UserRole ur = [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id =: selectedRole];  

        Setting__c newSetting = new Setting__c();

        newSetting.Name = settingRec.Name;
        newSetting.Status__c = selectedStat;
        newSetting.Role_ID__c = selectedRole;
        newSetting.Role_Name__c = ur.Name;

        insert newSetting;

        if(swList !=null && !swList.isEmpty()) {

            for(SettingWrapper sRec : swList) {

                Item__c iTemp = new Item__c();
                iTemp.Lookup__c = iTemp.set1.Lookup__c; 
                iTemp.Setting__c = newSetting.Id; 
                newItemList.add(iTemp);
            }
        }

        if(!newItemList.isEmpty()) {
                insert newItemList;
        }    

        PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/' + newSetting.Id);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }

    public class SettingWrapper {

        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public Setting__c set1 {get;set;}

    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Setting__c" extensions="SettingClass">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Setting__c" subtitle="New Setting"/>
    <apex:pageMessages /> 
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Setting" mode="edit">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />                 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Name"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!settingRec.Name}"/>                 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Role Name"/>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRole}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!UserRoleList}"/> 
                    </apex:selectList>                 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Status"/>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedStat}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!StatList}"/> 
                    </apex:selectList>                 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">
                <apex:outputPanel id="tablepanel">
                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!swraplist}" var="s">

                        <apex:column headerValue="Action" style="width:80px">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Remove" style="color:red" action="{!removeRow}" rendered="{!rowNum > 0}" rerender="tablepanel" immediate="true" > 
                                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="rowToRemove" assignTo="{!rowToRemove}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Survey Summary Form" >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!s.set1.Lookup__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <apex:commandButton value="Add Item" action="{!addNewRow}" rerender="tablepanel"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class SettingClassTest {
    private static testMethod void InsertSettingRecord() {

        List<Setting__c> settingList = new List<Setting__c>();
        List<SettingClass.SettingWrapper> settingWrapper = new List<SettingClass.SettingWrapper>();
        Integer rowToRemove = 0;
        String selectedRole;

        SettingClass sc = new SettingClass(new ApexPages.StandardController(new Setting__c()));

        sc.getUserRoleList();
        con.getStatList();

        UserRole urole;
        System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()) {
          urole = new UserRole();
          urole.Name = 'New Role';
          insert urole;
        }

        selectedRole = urole.Id;

        List<Lookup__c> lookupList = new List<Lookup__c>();
        Lookup__c lk = new Lookup__c();
        lk.Name = 'Lookup 1';
        lookupList.add(lk);

        insert lookupList;
        System.assertequals(lookupList + '', 'lookupList');

        Test.startTest();

        Setting__c s = new Setting__c();
        s.Name = '1';
        s.Status__c = 'Status 1';
        s.Role_ID__c = selectedRole; 
        s.Role_Name__c = urole.Name;
        settingList.add(s);

        insert settingList;   
        System.assertequals(settingList + '', 'settingList');

        PageReference pg = Page.SettingPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
        ApexPages.StandardController pgCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(ad); 
        SettingClass sClass = new SettingClass(pgCon);

        sClass.addNewRow(); 
        sClass.rowToRemove = 1;
        sClass.removeRow();

        SettingClass.SettingWrapper setWrap = new SettingClass.SettingWrapper();

        for(Integer i=0; i<200; i++) {
            Item__c newItem = new Item__c();
            newItem.Lookup__c = lk.Id;
            newItem.Setting__c = s.Id;    
            setWrap.set1 = newItem;
            setWrap.index = 0;
            settingWrapper.add(setWrap);
        }

        PageReference pg1 = Page.SettingPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pg1); 
        ApexPages.StandardController pgCon1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(ad);
        SettingClass sClass2 = new SettingClass(pgCon1);

        for(SettingClass.SettingWrapper setWrap2 : settingWrapper) {
            sClass2.swraplist.remove(0);
            sClass2.swraplist.add(swrap);
        }

        sClass2.save(); 

        Test.stopTest();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List has no rows for assignment to SObject - Test Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115821/list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject-test-class)

Comment: I don't think it's strictly a duplicate. There is a different underlying cause for the `QueryException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error always occurs when you directly assign the result of a query to a single Sobject variable, and the query returns no results.

To prevent the exception, simply assign to a `List`:

```
List<UserRole> ur = [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id =: selectedRole];
```

And then check the size of the returned list to determine how to proceed, and report errors to the user appropriately.

You should also check `selectedRole` for nullity, since it's under user control.

Now that's the exception *as such*. You have a different issue here that's the root cause: you're never assigning the `selectedRole` instance variable in your controller. You only assign it to a local variable in your test class and a field in your custom setting, so it's `null` when the query goes off.

Comment: Great! Just the explanation I need. Thank you so much David for your help :))

Comment: @curdual Can I just chime in and say that I would define selectedRole as an Id, not a String. While it is, technically, a String, the system will ensure that the value of selectedRole is always fitting the Id constraints (length, etc) so I tend to define IDs as such. Maybe I'm nit-picking, but it's just what I do.